# Is there any method to bind localhost + port to custom hostname

Tags: .net, reverse-proxy, blazor-server-side, ms-yarp

I just tried to set up a reverse proxy in blazor web server application with YARP. When I built it, it runs on localhost:5278. I just want to change adress with something else like [www.mybeautifultestsite.com](http://www.mybeautifultestsite.com). Editing the hosts file does not enable me to bind to http:://www.mybeautifultestsite.com on the 5278 port. I still need to use http:://www.mybeautifultestsite.com:5278 to reach it. Is there any method for this? Here my appsettings.json file. Thanks in advance.

```
"ReverseProxy": {
 "Routes": {
  "api-route": {
    "ClusterId": "api-cluster",
    "Match": {
      "Host": "www.mybeautifultestsite.com",
      "Path": "{**catch-all}"
    }
  }
},
"Clusters": {
  "api-cluster": {
    "Destinations": {
      "api-destination": {
        "Address": "http://127.0.0.1:5278"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}
}

Comment: The host name is resolved by DNS, not proxies like YARP. The OS itself resolves the host name to an IP and sends the request there. For development you can modify the `hosts` file and add entries that map whatever host you want to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: You need to instruct Kestrel to listen on port 80 instead.

Comment: I have already change the host file it didn't work but thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-8.0) Kestrel will listen on a random port between 5000-5300 (7000-7300 for HTTPS).

In addition to adding the hostname to the hosts file you need to instruct Kestrel to listen on port 80. Something like this:

```
{
  // Kestrel
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://[::]:80",
        "Protocols": "Http1AndHttp2"
      },
    }
  },

  // YARP
  "ReverseProxy": {
    "Routes": {
      "api-route": {
        "ClusterId": "api-cluster",
          "Match": {
            "Host": "www.mybeautifultestsite.com",
            "Path": "{**catch-all}"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Clusters": {
      "api-cluster": {
        "Destinations": {
          "api-destination": {
            "Address": "http://127.0.0.1:5278"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

***Disclaimer: Not tested***

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I have tried your solution but result not changed

Comment: In a second view, it worked quite perfectly. Just did some typos first time but now it works very well. Thank you so much for your effort.